# Generate a random number that excludes specific characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to generate 36 length random number that doest have 0, 1 or 6 number in it. What I  did is something like that

```
declare @random char(36)
set @random = newid()

set @random = replace(replace(replace(@random,'6','2'),'1','2'),'0','2')
select @random
```

I converted 6,1,0 to 2 but probably this isnt the best way to do that in sql server. What is the proper way to solve this problem ?

Comment: This numbers will be coupons' numbers. Actually even if I dont know the reason because the customer wants it to generate that way, I guess the reason can be the similarity of O, I, G and 0, 1, 6. I have shortened the question but the excluded characters are O,I,G,0,1,6

Comment: A random "number" - that can't contain 3 digits, but can contain letters a-f?

Comment: Don't know much SQL Server, but doesn't newid give you a GUID? Which wouldn't contain O, I, or G anyway?

Comment: It looks like you need 32 digits, wherein each digit is from the string "2345789ABCDEF". Is that correct?

Comment: Then I should choice a different way

Comment: @JohnPick I need all alphabet excludes O, I , G  and numbers excludes 0,1,6

Comment: Then you cannot use newid() which doesn't use any letters past f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

http://www.brettb.com/SQL_Help_Random_Strings.asp